# Showing paper-dropdown-menu when selected value in another

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to show a `paper-dropdown-menu` only when a specific value is selected in another `paper-dropdown-menu`.

I am using a property called `selectedValue` to bind selected value to the `if` attribute in a `dom-if` template.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="One" no-animations>
            <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedValue}}">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[options1]]">
                    <paper-item>[[item]]</paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <template is="dom-if" if="[[_view()]]">
            <paper-dropdown-menu label="Two" no-animations>
                <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[options2]]">
                        <paper-item>[[item]]</paper-item>
                    </template>
                </paper-listbox>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>
        </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        /**
        * @customElement
        * @polymer
        */
        class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'my-element'; }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    selectedValue : {
                        type : String
                    },
                    options1 : {
                        type: Array,
                        value: [1,2,3,4]
                    },
                    options2 : {
                        type: Array,
                        value : [5,6,7]
                    }
                };
            }

            _view() {
                return this.selectedValue === "1";
            }
        }

        window.customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is the second `paper-dropdown-menu` is never displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your computed binding has no dependencies, so it's invoked **once** at initialization. Since `selectedValue` is initially `undefined`, `_view()` returns `false`, causing the `dom-if` to hide its contents.

To cause the computed binding to re-evaluate `selectedValue`, make sure to specify the variable as an argument to the binding:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_view(selectedValue)]]">...</template>
```

Also note that `<paper-listbox>.selected` (to which `selectedValue` is bound) is a `number` by default (i.e., the index of the selected item), so this expression always evaluates to `false`:

```
selectedValue === "1"
```

I recommend switching the literal from a `string` to a `number`:

```
selectedValue === 1
```

So, the `_view` function should look like this:

```
_view(selectedValue) {
  return selectedValue === 1;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pPmydb?editors=1000)

Comment: fantastic, your are right! However, there is a problem: In your demo, second menu is displayed when I choose second option (`2`) and it should be displayed when I choose first option (`1`).  The problem is `selectedValue` holds selected index and not the selected value. Why?

Comment: The docs indicate that `<paper-listbox>.selected` is the index of the selected item by default. In order to use the item's value instead, you'd have to set an attribute of the item to the desired value, and then specify the attribute's name in `<paper-listbox>.attrForSelected`.